# Extracting fields from a database using Flask and jinja2

Tags: flask, jinja2

I am developing my code in Pythonanywhere. I am trying to modify and extend some code from a course.

I am modifying code that prints records from a database in order to extract a particular field value from each record, then find the maximum value of all values of that field in the database.

I have copied and renamed the following code within flask_app.py that just gets all records from the database

```
@app.route('/listmaxidv2')
def listmaxidv2():
with sqlite3.connect("MyFilms2.db") as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = """SELECT * FROM tblFilms"""
    cursor.execute(sql)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    return render_template("/listmaxidv2.html", rows=rows)
```

then in the listmaxidv2.html template that gets rendered, I am trying to isolate each value of that first field. I have tried quite a few things and my last attempt was as below but i am not sure the javascript is actualy executing (yes it is a bit of a mess). Is there something obvious in this that indicates why I'm not getting at the first fields in the records?

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/filmv2.css">
<script>
function getids(in_var){

if (isNaN(in_var)){

var ret_val = "invalid film id" + in_var;
}
else{
var ret_val = "Valid film id" + in_var;
}
return ret_val;
}
var func_ret = 0
{% for row in rows %}

func_ret =  getids({{row[0]}});
document.getElementById("id_fdbk").innerHTML = func_ret;
func_ret;
{% endfor %}
document.getElementById("testHTML").innerHTML = "Test text to HTML id";

</script>

<body>

<h1> Find maximum film ID </h1>
<h2> Generate next free film ID </h2>
<input type='button' value='Go' onclick='getids(017)';'>
<p id="id_fdbk"></p>
<p id="testHTML"></p>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the way Jinja works... Jinja in a python library, hence, it executes **server side** and javascript code executes **client side** so you can't mix the two as you're trying to do here...

Good news is you can adjust for this fairly simply like so...

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/filmv2.css">
<script>

    var raw_data = {{ rows|tojson }};

    function getids(in_var){
        return isNaN(in_var) ? "invalid film id" + in_var : "Valid film id" + in_var;
    }
    var func_ret = 0

    raw_data.forEach(function(row) {
        func_ret =  getids(row);
        document.getElementById("id_fdbk").innerHTML = func_ret;
    });

    document.getElementById("testHTML").innerHTML = "Test text to HTML id";

</script>

<body>

<h1> Find maximum film ID </h1>
<h2> Generate next free film ID </h2>
<input type='button' value='Go' onclick='getids(017)';'>
<p id="id_fdbk"></p>
<p id="testHTML"></p>


</body>

</html>
```

I couldn't quite make out what you are trying to do above. E.g. this code is just going to overwrite the same HTML element for each item in your list. I suspect you are just trying to get something working...

By using the Jinja's [**tojson**](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/templating/#standard-filters) filter you can tell Jinja to pass this information into your template so that javascript may use this as a native object.

Please note if you're using **Flask < 0.10** you would also need the `safe` filter like they have shown in the documentation linked above. (I.e. `var raw_data = {{ rows|tojson|safe }};`)

Comment: Hello. thank you for your help. yes you are quite right, I am just trying to get something working so I get some idea how this works. I didn't understand this separation of server side code from the javascript that runs in the browser client. I suppose relative to my limited understanding of how the components interact I am trying to run before I can walk.

Comment: Actually a very common issue so I wouldn't feel too bad! The way I think about it is Jinja stuff happens before the browser receives the page... you'll see this in the browser if you click "View Source"